# Can't find a source file at" /getc.c" eclipse c ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, fgetc

just installed eclipse on my linux and trying working with files.
I wanted to use fgetc function but it seems that its not working..
while debugging: even if Im using step over its crush, and while letting it run its just dont do anything. 
its happen also for every function related to files like fscanf,fgets etc..

the error messege is:

`Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/libio/getc.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.`

any ideas?

thnk's in advanced

and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    func();
return 0;
}

void func(){
  int ch;
  int fd = open("out.txt", O_RDONLY);
  if(fd < 0)
          perror("fd");
  ch = fgetc(fd);
  printf("%d",ch);
}
```

Comment: Don't try to trace through library functions.   Just use the *trace-over* or if you mistakenly get into them *finish* commands.  Whatever your actual issue *with your program* is, it is elsewhere.

Comment: if i understood you correctly so I really didnt trace, I debbuged it with step over and not step into

Comment: If you stepped over it properly you wouldn't have seen this.  But even so, it is *irrelevant*.  Focus on debugging the unexpected behavior.

Comment: what do you mean by properly? it's just pressing the button of step over..
anyway, any ideas for unexpected behavior?

Comment: Frankly your code should not even *compile* with a severe warning since you are mixing file descriptors and FILE handles, along with a few other issues like a missing prototoype and a missing include...

Comment: can you explain yourself?

Comment: Actually *read* the compiler warnings next time.  If you chose to disregard them, you are saying that you know the situation better than the compiler does.  *Sometimes* that might be true, but in this case, you clearly don't.

Comment: have your downloaded all the source files for the libraries?  If not, then, of course, the debugger cannot find them

Comment: regarding: `if(fd < 0)
          perror("fd");`  when the call to `open()` fails, do NOT continue to execute the code.  Rather the next statement (in side the body of the `if()` statement) should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   This is another good reason to always include the braces '{}`

Answer (score 2):

The error message comes from the debugger.  It indicates that whoever built glibc for your system did not add source files to the debugging information.  As a result, stepping through system library functions such as `fgetc` is very confusing.  But this is independent of your actual problem.

You cannot mix file descriptor functions like `open` with file stream functions like `fgetc`.  The compiler will have print a type mismatch warning; you really should not ignore these.

Something like this should fix the type error:

```
  File *fp = fopen("out.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }
  ch = fgetc(fp);
```

If you want to keep using unbuffered I/O and `open`, you will have to use the `read` function instead of `fgetc` to read bytes.

Comment: It did worked with read but I wasnt sure why..
thank you very much!!